# How to get letter width?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, typography, extendscript

I'm working on an Illustrator script (javascript) and I need to measure the width of a letter. This letter is a TextFrameItem with only one character:

[image]

The object has an attribute .width which gives the width of the bounding box above.

The length I need to know is the one of the blue baseline.

Any idea to measure it?

Comment: Is that the TextPath? If so (for CS6-and-later), you could try inspecting its pathPoints.

Comment: No, it's a PointText (text.kind = TextType.POINTTEXT). I don't know either how to get the coordinates of the origin point. The top/left attributes are relatives to the bounding box too. However, I can get the rotation matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way I have found to get the width of text is to rasterize the textlayer (dup a copy if you need to retain the original textlayer for later) and then work off the bounds of the rasterized layer.

Comment: good idea, but in my case I have thousands texts to deal with, so for performance troubles, I think it's not conceivable.